# AngularJS: How do i capture the value of selected option in the function?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on cordova application that consist of angularJS. I have a code snippet as follows:

```
                <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    Select Team
                </div>
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="deviceEach in devices" id="{{deviceEach.id}}">{{deviceEach.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </label>

            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user Email" ng-model="newuser.username">
            </label>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="userSubmit(newuser)" class="button button-calm">
                Add User
            </button>
```

When user click on add User button it should capture the value of selected option Id and username entered. I can capture the value of input tag but how to capture the value of select tag selected option?

Comment: Try <select ng-model="newuser.selectModel"></select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the select element use ng-model

```
<select ng-model="selectedValue" >
   <option ng-repeat="deviceEach in devices" id="{{deviceEach.id}}">{{deviceEach.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: yes if you want after you can store it in another variable but if you you want to post your newUser, yes it could be newUser.device